# Port is free, but Apache fails with: "Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address"

Tags: apache-2.2, rhel4

Apache (Linux Red Hat 4.1.x) fails to start with message:  "Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address".

```
# /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: 
make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8000
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Already tried to do:

```
killall -9 httpd
```

It looks like Apache is not running.
The port 8000 if free so nothing prevents Apache to occupy it. (nginx is on :80 as reverse proxy)

```
 # netstat -tulpn| grep :80
 tcp  0   0 0.0.0.0:8001    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN 17181/DarwinStreami
 tcp  0   0 0.0.0.0:80      0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN 7962/nginx.conf
```

Possibly someone will have any thoughts on how to fix this?

**UPD1:** Apache config options are:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 120
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       1
MinSpareServers   5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit     200
MaxClients  200
MaxRequestsPerChild 2000

User apache
Group apache

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

NameVirtualHost *:8000
```

**UPD2:** Pid is not found:

```
# ls /etc/httpd/run/*.pid
/etc/httpd/run/crond.pid          /etc/httpd/run/sshd.pid
/etc/httpd/run/dhclient-eth0.pid  /etc/httpd/run/streamingadminserver.pid
/etc/httpd/run/haldaemon.pid      /etc/httpd/run/syslogd.pid
/etc/httpd/run/messagebus.pid     /etc/httpd/run/syslog-ng.pid
/etc/httpd/run/nginx.pid          /etc/httpd/run/xfs.pid
```

**UPD3:** server reboot doesn't helps ;)

**UPD4:** `nc -l 8000` works OK, so the problem is not with a 8000 port but with Apache itself.

**UPD5:** "# /usr/sbin/lsof -i :8000" - outputs nothing

Comment: Could you post the main part of your Apache config (with any identifying information taken out, of course)

Comment: updated initial question

Comment: selinux problem? Add 8000 to the httpd ports.

Comment: in case of "selinux" problem is can produce the "Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied" but not "Address already in use"

Comment: If you've got `nc` installed, you could try binding that to port 80 to see if it's just Apache that's having problems or something really is holding it open - `nc -l -p 80` should do it.

Comment: "# nc -l 8000" works OK, so the problem is with Apache itself

Comment: I was able to connect with "# nc 127.0.0.1 8000" and send messages to nc listener on 8000 port

Comment: Can you share the output of `lsof -i :8000` ?

Comment: "# /usr/sbin/lsof -i :8000" - outputs nothing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have Listen directive for the same socket multiple times. Use `grep -r Listen /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to find the culprit.

From [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen):

> Error condition
>   Multiple Listen directives for the same ip address and port will result in an Address already in use error message.

Comment: Thanks!! "# grep -r Listen /etc/httpd/" produced the list of directives where I was able to locale 8000 port value multiple times. Hope this thread will help everyone to debug such issues in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I get this sometimes when the PID file wasn't removed during the previous apache stop.  If the PID is there, try removing it before starting up again.

I also get this sometimes when I'm trying to start apache up using an account other than what apache was configured to run as.

Comment: according to Apache configuration we have "PidFile run/httpd.pid", where can I find that file?

Comment: Ok,finally wasn't able to locale that file under "/etc/httpd/run/"

Comment: Anyway thanks for your attention!
My case was about accidentally declaring "Listen" multiple times, while dealing with sub-domains and multiple system administrators on the same server :)